# placing pdf files with keywords on many different wordpress sites

Tags: seo, wordpress, keywords

I do a daily search for my primary keyword phrases just to see what comes up. The past couple of months Google results show 2-4 new items every day and each is a pdf file at a different `wordpress.com` site. For example, `https://somejunk.files.wordpress.com`. "somejunk" is just an example, of course, but it is always a meaningless name that very much appears to be computer generated. Each pdf has several short snippets of text containing relevant content, including my primary keywords, but from several different websites, often from my website, but mostly from competitors' websites. There are no links in these pdf files. Maybe this is being done by someone with an interest in my primary keywords, perhaps a competitor.

Is this some sort of SEO strategy?

How would it benefit anyone if it does not contain backlinks?

Also, does it represent a violation of my copyright when a short, partial sentence from my website is used?

Comment: It is likely not a copyright infringement if it is only a sentence unless you can show a pattern of intentional behavior and harm and can prove that the sentence is yours and not from another source. As well, I am not sure what the payoff is, but you can file a DMCA complaint with Google and contact Wordpress. If there is a targeted pattern that you can absolutely prove, hire an attorney!! Otherwise, do no depend on keywords and certainly not just a few. It is a bad idea. Do not do the keyword chase.